# How to parse all URLs from a page using Google Script?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to extract all the urls from remote url using GAS but my current code gives me no data. could any one tell me what is the correct regex pattern should i use so i get all the http urls ? The array content using logger.log is always empty!

```
function getURLS()
{

  var url = "http://www.someurlgoeshere.com/";
  var options =
  {
    headers : {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0'}
  };


  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();


    var inner_links_arr= [];
     var linkRegExp = /http"(.*?)"/gi; // regex expression object

    var match = linkRegExp.exec(html);
    while (match != null) 
    {


      inner_links_arr.push(match[1]);

    } //end of while

  Logger.log(inner_links_arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . i even tried that nothing get pushed to the array! i even tried to put html="http://www.stackoverflow.com/"; and the url didn't get added to array!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex isn't matching correctly. You can test your regex with many different online tools and verify they are matching correctly.

[See this from regexr.com](http://regexr.com/39psu)

```
((https?|ftp)://|www\.)[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*
```

The first group of parens, matches either www. or https/http/ftp://
The outer group of parens, then matches anything thats not a whitespace, /, $, ., ? or # and then the last part, matches anything after the dot that's not a whitespace

Comment: i tried to use the regex expression you suggested but it gives me syntax error  var linkRegExp = ((https?|ftp)://|www\.)[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*/gi;